# Derived store populated by async request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, svelte

In svelte, I have a store `parent`:

```js
// parent.js
import { writable } from "svelte/store"

let parent = writable('')

export default parent
```

I now want to create a derived store `child`, which fetches additional data from an external API in an asynchronous request. In my views, I would like to await `child` to be populated with the updated date when I display its contents.

I have worked myself through the examples of stores on svelte.dev, but I was not able to come up with a solution.

I tried to different things, but I feel I lack understanding of how a derived store works in svelte.

Comment: The `parent` within the writable argument makes no sense, it references the store itself.

Comment: @H.B.Thanks, sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call an async function in the `derived` callback and then await the store content, e.g.

```js
const child = derived(parent, $parent => (async () => {
    // Delay to simulate a long API call
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500));
    
    return {
        parent: $parent,
        child: new Date(), // Some new child data here
    };
})()); // <- Immediately invoked async function
```

(The async function could also be extracted, of course; it would need an argument for the `$parent` then, as it would no longer form a closure.)

```html
{#await $child then childData}
  ...
{/await}
```

[REPL Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/09c1bfba1af84b30bc10ab6267a1ad5f?version=3.50.1)

On every change to the `parent` store, the `child` store will call the async function again, returning a new promise.